# Why original query reported 301 error after data migration to Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.0?

Tags: time-series, migrate, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I just migrated my data from Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.2 to Version 1.0.0. When I tried to execute the original sql query, it failed and reported this 301 error: Declared positions (811) does not match column 0's number of entries (735). I am doing aggregation query on time and device level, does the explanation mean that this error is because my set field did not contain specific value within my queried time period?

I checked the official guide on the official website, but cannot find the relevant information to solve this error. I also cannot change the original query statement due to business needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this seems to be an error caused by tsfile merging error. You can try to upgrade to Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.1, since this bug should have been fixed in Version 1.0.1 and the afterward versions